# Why would (head sum) leads a type error? (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, typing

I have tried `:t head sum` in the Ghci and get a type error result.

For my own thinking, it should be `[int] -> int`.

Also, I have tried `:t sum head` in the Ghci and get `a` result.

I get confused for these answers.
Could someone help me figure out that?

`head` and `sum` functions shows below:

`head :: [a] -> a`

`sum :: [Int] -> Int`

Comment: Since when has `[a]` been equal to `[Int] -> Int`?

Answer (score 3):

For the first one: `head` expects a list, `sum` is a function. Hence, they can not be applied.

About the second one: with the new GHC 7.10 class redesign, `sum head` type checks, but has a useless type:

```
> :t sum head
sum head :: (Num a, Foldable ((->) [a])) => a
```

Note the constraint `Foldable ((->) [a])`. To fulfill such constraint we would need to define, roughly, a conversion function from

```
[a] -> b
```

and

```
[b]
```

for any choice of `b`. This can not really be done, so `sum head` is not practically usable.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried :t head sum in the Ghci and get a type error result.

`head` returns the first element of a list, sum reduces a list of num into a single num. Since head take a list it cant take a single int as parameter, thats why `head sum` throws a type error.
Notice that you have not check it properly in ghci, the type of sum is:

```
Prelude> :t sum
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

> Also, I have tried :t sum head in the Ghci and get a result.

As you just saw, `head` is of type `[a] -> a` and sum is of type `Num a => [a] -> a`, so If `head` returns an `a` and asuming that `a` can be of any type, including a `Num a => [a]` or in plain english, a list of numerals wich can be taken by `sum` and where `sum` will reduce it and return an `a` (wich is a Num).
So, the type for `sum . head` is:

```
Prelude> :t sum . head
sum . head :: Num c => [[c]] -> c
```

Mapping to the previous explanation, the `[a]` from the `head` is now `[c]`, the `[a]` from `sum` is `[[c]]` and the final returned result from our previous `a` is `c` wich is also a Num (numeral).

Comment: You are confusing `head sum` with `head . sum`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs, just notice it, you are right, sorry